# Azure Deployment Slot Swap Scheduling

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-appservice

I have an app service with two deployment slots: Production and Test. My current flow is that I push my changes to Devops, the build kicks off, and a release is created in Test.

I can then go to the Test url, do some testing, and when ready, I can swap the two slots.

What I would like to do is schedule a time for a swap so it's automated at say, 2 or 3 am when traffic is almost nil. Is there a way to automate the swap either through the interface (99% sure that's not available) or through a script that gets triggered somehow?

Answer (score 0):

***Deployed .NET Web App to the Azure App Service having deployment slots - Staging and Production***.

**In Pre-deployment Conditions > Triggers > Schedule - Monday to Friday at 6 AM is set**.

I have created the release and the production slot is evaluated after staging slot deployment and scheduled time:

[image]

You have to set the schedule on Pre-deployment conditions of the Prod Slot in the Release Pipeline:

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

[image]

Changed Prod Slot Functionality from deployment to Swap Slots.

[image]

*Schedule worked for the Swap Slots Stages in release Pipeline*.

Comment: Thank you. Is this actually swapping the slots, or just pushing to the Prod slot at a later time? My requirements are to swap the slots so that the site is already warmed up, and so that they can be swapped back quickly if there's an issue.

Comment: This is pushing the new code artifacts to the Prod Slot at a later time.

Comment: Checked for swapping the slots also, it worked.

Comment: I don't know what you mean in your 2nd statement.  If you push to Staging, then later push to Prod, they both will have the same codebase. I'm looking to schedule a swap only.